# DatePicker always resetting to todays date in the Details Page

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a TasksGroup which contains multiple Tasks, when i click add, i add a new GroupTasks which also contains the data to create the first Tasks.

**Tasks objects keep their datas in the filling form, but TasksGroup objects reset to their intial value or none if they don't have a preset value.**

When i fill out the form, there's a date picker which i initialize to todays date and when saved the date appear to the left of the TasksGroup ( see picture ), but let's  say i wanna add a new Task, the DatePicker won't set to the GroupTasks date ( left colored date on picture )

[image: How the date is displayed]

On the picture, you can see that the date is 03 july, but let's say i click on one of the Task to access the TasksDetailsPage ( in the Tache part) the date picker will reset to todays date, which is 6 july (see picture) ALSO i have a GroupTasksDescription which will reset to 0. But all the other data that is a part of a Tasks is keeping their good Data.

[image: DatePicker in filling form]

Thanks for your help !

**NewTaskPage.xaml which is the form filling**

```
    <Label Text="Date de calcul:" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="ROBOTO" TextColor="#000000"></Label>
        <DatePicker   Date="{Binding TasksGroupDate}" FontFamily="ROBOTO" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" ></DatePicker>

    </StackLayout>
```

**NewTaskPageViewModel.cs constructor which has Date initialized to Todays when you add a new GroupTask because if i don't do that it goes to 1 january 1900.**

```
public NewTaskPageViewModel()
{
    
   this.TasksGroupDate = DateTime.Now;

    
    SaveNewTaskCommand = new Command(async () => await SaveNewTask(), () => !IsBusy);
    
}
```

**TasksGroupPage.xaml TasksGroup binding which is the main page u see on first picture**

```
 <Label Text="{Binding TasksGroupDate , StringFormat='{0:dd}'}" TextColor="#008A00" FontSize="27" 
                                                   HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

                                                    <Label Text="{Binding TasksGroupDate , StringFormat='{0:MMMM}'}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="10" 
                                                   HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="0,-10,0,0" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
```

**TasksGroupPage.xaml.cs method to open the Details page**

```
async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new TasksDetailsPage
        {
            BindingContext = e.SelectedItem as Tasks
        });
    }
}
```

**TasksDetailsPage.xaml**

```
    <StackLayout >
        <Label Text="Date de calcul:" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="ROBOTO" TextColor="#000000"></Label>
        <DatePicker   Date="{Binding TasksGroupDate}" FontFamily="ROBOTO" Format="yyyy-MM-dd" ></DatePicker>

    </StackLayout>
    
    <StackLayout >
        <Label Text="Description de la journée" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="ROBOTO" TextColor="#000000"></Label>
        <Entry x:Name="TasksGroupDescription" Text="{Binding TasksGroupDescription}"/>
        
    </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="Durée quotidienne" FontAttributes="Bold" FontFamily="ROBOTO" TextColor="#000000"></Label>
        <Entry x:Name="TaskDuration" Placeholder="HH:MM:SS" Text="{Binding TaskDuration}"/>
    </StackLayout>
```

**TasksDetailsPage.xaml.cs**

```
public TasksDetailsPage ()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    
   BindingContext = new TasksGroupDetailsPageViewModel();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to solve my problem with just adding this to my TasksGroup data binding in TasksDetailsPage.xaml :

```
Date="{Binding TasksGroup.TasksGroupDate}"
```

Answer (score 0):

here, you are setting the `BindingContext` to the selected `Task`

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new TasksDetailsPage
    {
        BindingContext = e.SelectedItem as Tasks
    });
```

then here you are setting it to `new TasksGroupDetailsPageViewModel()`

```
public TasksDetailsPage ()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    BindingContext = new TasksGroupDetailsPageViewModel();
}
```

you are overwriting one with the other, and they appear to be using two completely different types

Comment: Ok, but if my filling form contains GroupTasks data and Tasks data also, how would i change this to keep both of my datas ? Cause i think you can just set one binding context. Thanks.

Comment: modify your VM to have both.  Or pass one in as an argument to your page.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but i am not sure on how to implement it, i understand that currently when i open my TasksDetailsPage i am setting the binding context to Tasks, but this only get the data for a Tasks and now if i understand, i need to also get the data for a GroupTasks how can i give my VM both ? thanks

Comment: create two properties on your VM, one for Tasks and one for GroupTasks, then your page will have access to both pieces of data

Comment: i added this to TasksDetailsPageViewModel :         public TasksGroup tasksGroup { get; set; } = new TasksGroup();
        public Tasks tasks { get; set; } = new Tasks(); and in  TasksDetailsPage.xaml.cs i did this : 
            BindingContext = new TasksDetailsPageViewModel();

            var vm = this.BindingContext as TasksDetailsPageViewModel;
            this.Datepicker.BindingContext = vm.tasksGroup.TasksGroupDate; without any success maybe we could open a chat quick ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a value of Date to today's date and Binding it with variable
TasksGroupDate. set DisplayDate property to today's date and get the date when selection is done and if the selection is null then assign to a default date or you can use SelectionChanged property and manage it accordingly when the selection of datepicker is changed. Hope this helps you.